# Setup hangout button in my website

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-hangouts

I have strange problem. I'm trying to integrate hangout button in my website to enable user to open the lecture directly from the website  and I used the sample code in Google Hangout API Documentation 
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#hangout_button_code
button it didn't work, so what is the problem ?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>   </script>
<div id="placeholder-div3"></div>
<script>
 gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div3', {
'render': 'createhangout',
'hangout_type': 'onair',
'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
'widget_size': 175
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your problem has to do with the fact that you are deferring your library script, but not `gapi.hangout.render` script.  So, my guess is your `gapi.hangout.render` code is running before the library it utilizes ever gets to load.

Try just removing the `async` and `defer` attributes and see if that works for you.

The async I would imagine might also cause problems if your `render` method is getting called before the library loads fully.

Answer (score 0):

To follow-up, I looked at the gapi.hangout.render method and it's not clear about the first parameter, but disregard my previous answer and try this:

```
<script>
 gapi.hangout.render(document.querySelector('#placeholder-div3'), {
'render': 'createhangout',
'hangout_type': 'onair',
'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
'widget_size': 175
 });
</script>
```